# Django Models not working: module 'django.contrib.admin' has no attribute 'Modeladmin'

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-admin

I am making a eCommerce website from a youtube tutorial and I have an error that is really bugging me around.

I tried google but it didn't work. Then I tried messing with Django but that made it worse, so I changed it back.

This is the code for admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin

# Register your models here.
from .models import profiles

class profileadmin(admin.Modeladmin):
    class Meta:
        model = profiles

admin.site.register(profiles, profileadmin)
```

The full error message is this:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x03ED28A0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\roche\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\roche\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Users\roche\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 248, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "C:\Users\roche\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 337, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "C:\Users\roche\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\roche\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\roche\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 120, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "C:\Users\roche\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\apps.py", line 24, in ready
    self.module.autodiscover()
  File "C:\Users\roche\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\__init__.py", line 26, in autodiscover
    autodiscover_modules('admin', register_to=site)
  File "C:\Users\roche\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 47, in autodiscover_modules
    import_module('%s.%s' % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
  File "C:\Users\roche\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\roche\WebApp\WebApp\profiles\admin.py", line 6, in <module>
    class profileadmin(admin.Modeladmin):
AttributeError: module 'django.contrib.admin' has no attribute 'Modeladmin'
```

Comment: It should be `admin.ModelAdmin` not `admin.Modeladmin`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try to update your code as this :

```
from django.contrib import 
admin.ModelAdmin as admin
```

Then

```
class profileadmin(admin):
```

You can find more information about django imports here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields

Comment: if any of my other posts are helpful, be sure to upvote and reply to them.

Comment: I marked the correct answer back, and I just looked at @Sushanth S. B's docs first and it was the same as yours.

Comment: As Sushanth S.B said: It is ModelAdmin not Modeladmin. docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-objects

Answer (score 4):

It is **ModelAdmin** not **Modeladmin**.
[docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-objects)

Comment: I just looked at the tutorial and found out that you were right. Anyway, Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```
from django.contrib import admin

# Register your models here.
from .models import profiles

class profileadmin(admin.Modeladmin): #the error is in this line
    class Meta:
        model = profiles

admin.site.register(profiles, profileadmin)

The correct format suppose to be 
class profileadmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
```